# What mode does the command `query-replace' activate?

Tags: key-bindings, query-replace

I'm editing my keybinds mode-by-mode, and I've now come to the `query-replace-map`.

I want to define my keybinds in a mode-hook to keep my files logically consistent, but I cannot determine which mode the command `query-replace` activates.

I've tried <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-mode`, but activating the minibuffer immediately disables `query-replace`, thus I cannot look at the list of modes the buffer is currently in.

Or are `query-replace`/`isearch-query-replace` even modes?
If not, what sort of functionality is this, and how should I handle the rebinding of keys in these peculiarities (using mode-hooks or any other method that I might not know of)?

Also are there any other caveats when dealing with these pseudo-modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query-replace` is just a command, it is not a major or minor mode. Before the phase in which it prompts for what to do with each match, it has no special bindings and uses `minibuffer-local-map` (this is where the usual keys for input history, `M-r`, `M-p` and `M-n` are bound, for example). The second phase uses `query-replace-map`.

If there is a particular keybinding you want to change, in recent versions of Emacs you can find out which keymap contains it by using `describe-key` (bound by default to `C-h k`). You can usually use that even while a command is prompting you in the minibuffer, which is how I found that `M-r` is bound in `minibuffer-local-map`

Unfortunately, that doesn't work for keys in the second phase of `query-replace`! So how did I find out what map is used then? Well, since it's name starts with `query-replace-map` I could have simply guessed, but what I actually did was read the source code of `query-replace` (which led me to `perform-replace` which is where `query-replace-map` is used).